# Not able to ping AWS ec2 IPv6 address

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have t3.small EC2 instance i have associated ipv6 address to it but not able to ping the address .

1.able to ping IPv4 of same instance

2.for reference i have used - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html (i think i have followed all steps correctly) but unable to ping still

3. To ping, I have used another IPV6 enabled instance to test. and also used IPV6 internet connection to do so.
4. VPC has two subnets one public and one private do i also have to make some changes in private subnet (i have used public subnet)
5. No error is showing just unable to ping (Do i have to stop and restart the instance ?)